# Crystal reports syntax error

Tags: c#, string, crystal-reports, count, syntax-error

I tried to make a simple report using the Crystal Reports for dot net.
But it returned wrong value “5” every time.
The correct value is “3”.
Here is my result.

```
   Desktop 
   Desktop
   Laptop
   Laptop
   Laptop
Total Laptop 5
```

And below code that I have used.

```
Local numberVar cnt := 0:
Local stringVar stv  := {Table_1.Property};
Local numberVar strLen := Count({Table_1.Property});
Local numberVar i;

For i := 1 to strLen do
(
   If stv = “Laptop”
   Then cnt := cnt + 1
Else cnt := cnt + 0
);
cnt;
```

Where was wrong this code?
Thanks:)

Comment: No need for Else cnt := cnt + 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assuming that the records are printed in the details section and the formula for the total is located in the footer section, you get the wrong result because in the `for` loop you are always reading the last record printed in the details section since the footer in being rendered **after** the details section.

As a solution you can use one of the following methods :

1. Solution with 2 formulas.

   - Create a formula called ItemCountDetails and add following code.

     ```
     WhilePrintingRecords;
     Shared NumberVar Cnt;

     if RecordNumber = 1 then
         Cnt:= 0;

     if {Table_1.Property} = "Laptop" then
         Cnt:= Cnt + 1;
     ```
   - Drag and drop the formula field somewhere on the details section (where your records will be printed) and suppress it by right clicking on the field -> Format Object -> Common Tab -> and checking the suppress CheckBox.
   - Create another formula called ItemCountFooter and add the following code.

     ```
     Shared NumberVar Cnt;
     ```
   - Drag and drop the new formula field in the footer section.
2. Solution with Summary and Grouping.

   - Right click inside a section and select Summary.
   - From the "Choose the field to summarize" select "Property" which is under Table_1.
   - From the "Calculate this summary" select "count"
   - Click insert group and from the common tab select "Property" from the first ComboBox.
   - Close the dialogs by clicking OK. On the report you will see a field for the name of the group and a field for the count.
   - Right click on the GroupHeaderSection1 bar and select Suppress.
   - Right click on the "Count of Table_1.Property" field -> Format Object -> Common Tab -> click the x+2 button which on the right side of the suppress Checkbox and add the following code there

     ```
     if GroupName({Table_1.Property}) <> "Laptop" then
         true
     else
         false
     ```